# Rails 3 activerecord children of children records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My models:

```
class Person
 has_many :projects

class Project
 belongs_to :person
 has_many :tasks

class Task
 belongs_to :project
```

Given a `person` instance, `person = Person.find(10)`, is there an easy way to access all the `tasks` that belongs to all the `projects` for the `person`? In addition, I would need to further filter the `projects` results if `projects.duration < x days` sort of thing. I could try to manually construct the resultset by `person.projects` and then looping through each `project` to get the associated `tasks` but I'm hoping there is another simpler more elegant syntax that I'm not aware of. BTW, `person.projects.tasks` doesn't work.

Comment: Dude, there's a similar question with a perfect answer to your question. [Ruby-on-rails-simple-way-to-select-all-records-of-a-nested-model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441357/ruby-on-rails-simple-way-to-select-all-records-of-a-nested-model)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is a more elegant way to do it. You can eager load the results. Let me show you.

without filtering the person list

```
person = Person.find(10).includes(:projects=>:tasks)
```

This will eager load you the results so if you call `person.projects.first.tasks.first` its already loaded and no more sql queries will be executed.

If you'd like to filter them do something like this:

```
person = Person.where('people.id=10 AND projects.duration < ?', x).includes(:projects=>:tasks)
```

If you'd like to iterate just on all the tasks without iterating through the projects you have to set up a relation like:

```
class Person
  has_many :projects
  has_many :tasks, :through=>:projects
end
```

To iterate them do something like:

```
person = Person.find(10)
person.tasks.where('projects.duration < ?', x)
```